# Show user movement between two networks in plantuml

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml

I am trying to create a sequence diagram where an actor participant moves between two network and performs few action. example: actor A1 access some Application from VLAN1 which goes via certain network nodes and then it moves to VLAN2 and access application which reach its server to via other network nodes.

I have created few diagrams already in plantuml earlier but this one seems pretty tricky. i am not sure if any other tool can help here but i shall prefer plantuml.

> A1--moves->VLAN1 ; A1--Access->App1; A1--Node1--node2-->App1 Server;
>   A1--moves->VLAN2; A1--Access->App1; A1--Node1--Node3-->App1 Server;

**Updated:**
following is the image that i ended up creating separately for VLAN1, similar one i have created for VLAN2.
[image: When User is in VLAN1]

Comment: Check https://sequencediagram.org/

Comment: This is another tool just like plantUML

Comment: Would be nice if you could share an image of what you want to reach.

Comment: _I am trying to create a diagram_ which kind of diagram ? a sequence diagram (tag) ? Out of that why to not use a _modeler_ rather than just a _drawer_ ?

Comment: ended up creating two separate sequence diagram for VLAN1 and VLAN2.

Comment: @VikasPushkar can you share something?

Comment: @albert please check the image above.

Comment: The shown picture is quite straight forward, but I don't get the relation between the picture for vlan 1 and vlan 2. Maybe you could add a (hand) draw) image of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @albert the path from Useramchine to App1 server is supposed to be different in case of VLAN1 and VLAN2. in platuml we have participant, database, actor and other stuff, i was wondering if similar thing is there for networks as well. another option i had was to mention the path from Usermachine to App1 server with a 'alt VLAN1 case,  else VLAN2 case, end case' when the sequence diagram did not look good in that.

Comment: @VikasPushkar Please add your ALT / ELSE diagram so we can better understand what you want.